# Using data from mysql in an excel pivot table

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc, pivot-table

I am using mysql for my datawarehouse. But I have several excel-users that want to connect to the data and use it in pivot-tables. I have tried:

- Mysql to excel:  I meet the problem with limited rows (1 mill +) and updtaing is not very easy.
- Mysql ODBC driver: This transferes the data to excel. But data is hidden and I can work with more than 1 mill rows. But if I have 12 mill rows, it runs out of memory.
- Mondrian: Have tried to use Mondirian and Saiku. Here you do the query on the mysql server which is good, but I loose functionality in the excel pivot table. I can not group or use the field function.

Is there anyone that knows of a solution for this problem with me continueing using mysql or do I have to crawl to the cross and start using MSSql?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Power query and Power Pivot excel add ins?

Comment: Tried it, but I did not find a solution with problem with the maximum possible rows.